# How to convert IoSliceMut array into Vec<u8>?

Tags: arrays, vector, rust, buffer, slice

```
let mut buffer = Vec::with_capacity(10);
stream.read_vectored(&mut buffer);
```

The code above turns `buffer` into an `IoSliceMut` vector, but I don't know how to read from this vector or how to convert it back into a `Vec<u8>`.

Comment: Unless you consumed the original `u8` vector, nothing happened to it, `read_vectored` is a way of referencing the original `stream`. When `buffer` goes out of scope, it's like all the references are gone and you can use original data as always

Comment: To read the data you iterate `buffer` and your can `Deref` each `IoSliceMut` into a slice of `u8` there are [plenty of methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.IoSliceMut.html#deref-methods) to read out of those.

Comment: @AlexLarionov Thanks for the input, I'll look into it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to convert the `IoSliceMut` structs back to `u8` arrays, the `read_vectored` writes the bytes directly into the array buffers since you pass them by mutable references. You can just use the buffers afterward and they will have the data written in them. Example:

```rust
use std::io::IoSliceMut;
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let mut buffer: [u8; 10] = [0; 10];
    let mut io_slices = [IoSliceMut::new(&mut buffer)];
    let mut data: &[u8] = &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    data.read_vectored(&mut io_slices);
    dbg!(data, buffer); // data is now in buffer
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ea3bfcc9119ad2a6248dd540f5b69560)

Comment: How to convert to Vec<u8> without copying, actually?